# Use widget inside TextFormField

Tags: flutter, input, textfield

I am in need to have a widget inside a TextFormField. For an example of what I need, see how [this library](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_text_field) uses images inline in the ExtendedTextField. I need that exact same thing, but instead of an inline image it would be an inline widget.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: I would be nice, if you can add your require UI here.

Comment: @KhyatiModi I updated the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74986894/how-to-use-flutter-extended-text-field-library thanks