# How to use Flutter Extended Text Field library

Tags: flutter, input, textfield

I would like to use the [extended_text_field](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_text_field) library using the WidgetSpan. There is an example on how to create an EmailText widget, but I don't understand how to integrate this into the ExtendedTextField. The documentation is not clear to me. Can someone post an example, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look [at my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74987906/12349734).

But in general, if you take a look [at the docs](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_text_field), you'll see that there are different classes that you can `extend`, such as `SpecialText`, `SpecialTextSpanBuilder`, and then you decide what you want to build.

This code example is taken from my above-linked answer.

If there's an @ symbol, it will be placed in a `Chip` widget:

> ```
> import 'package:extended_text_field/extended_text_field.dart';
> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
>
> const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);
>
> void main() {
>   runApp(MyApp());
> }
>
> class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return MaterialApp(
>       theme: ThemeData(
>         dividerColor: Colors.green,
>         scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
>       ),
>       debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
>       home: SafeArea(
>         child: Scaffold(
>           backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
>           body: ExtendedTextField(
>             cursorColor: Colors.black,
>             style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
>             decoration: InputDecoration(
>               border: OutlineInputBorder(),
>             ),
>             specialTextSpanBuilder: MySpecialTextSpanBuilder(),
>           ),
>         ),
>       ),
>     );
>   }
> }
>
> class MySpecialTextSpanBuilder extends SpecialTextSpanBuilder {
>   @override
>   TextSpan build(String data,
>       {TextStyle? textStyle, SpecialTextGestureTapCallback? onTap}) {
>     final lookingFor = "@";
>     final splitData = data.split(" ");
>     final spans = splitData.map((e) {
>       if (e == lookingFor) {
>         return WidgetSpan(
>           child: Chip(
>             label: Text(e),
>           ),
>         );
>       } else {
>         return TextSpan(
>           text: e,
>           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
>         );
>       }
>     }).toList();
>     return TextSpan(children: spans, style: textStyle);
>   }
>
>   @override
>   SpecialText? createSpecialText(String flag,
>       {TextStyle? textStyle,
>       SpecialTextGestureTapCallback? onTap,
>       required int index}) {
>     // TODO: implement createSpecialText
>     throw UnimplementedError();
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: I don't understand your logic.